# No Information Property List?

Tags: swift, xcode

on Apple's website it has "Information property list" instead of "Root" and I cannot add sub items for the items like they have? I do not understand I think I am doing this correct because all I did was make a new plist file. but it is incorrect?!? please help
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You can change the type of `Root` or the sub items in the `Type` column by clicking on `Dictionary` or `String`.
2. You can rename the sub items like renaming other objects in Xcode.
3. Hovering over the row shows a plus and minus sign.
4. There is also a context menu.
5. `Information Property List` is only displayed for the file `Info.plist` created by Xcode and accessible in the `Info` tab of the target.